# ForwardDiff.jl and ReverseDiff.jl error message related to ::getfield()

Tags: julia, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, automatic-differentiation

I am attempting to use the ForwardDiff.jl and / or ReverseDiff.jl libraries for computing the gradient in an optimization problem.

Both of these packages give me an error message related to ::getfield().

ReverseDiff gives me a LoadError:

```
 MethodError: no method matching (::getfield(CalibrationModule, Symbol("#f#4"))
 {AlgorithmParameters,ModelParameters,Guess,Array{Float64,1}})
 (::ReverseDiff.TrackedArray{Float64,Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}})
```

ForwardDiff gives me a LoadError:

```
 MethodError: no method matching (::getfield(CalibrationModule, Symbol("#f#10"))
 {AlgorithmParameters,ModelParameters,Guess,Array{Float64,1}})
 (::Array{ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{getfield(CalibrationModule,
 Symbol("#f#10"))     
 {AlgorithmParameters,ModelParameters,Guess,Array{Float64,1}},Float64},Float64,6},1})
```

I have no idea how to make sense of this error message. My code is too complicated to post here, but as far as I can tell I am not using any libraries not written in Julia. I do extensively use custom data types (mutable structs) throughout, but I don't see why this would cause a problem...

Answer (score 2):

Really hard to say without code, but:

A printout like `(::getfield(CalibrationModule, Symbol(...)){...}(...)` is how Julia displays anonymous functions and closures. You're getting a method error that this anonymous function or closure doesn't support a signature that takes an `Array` with either `Dual` or `Tracked` numbers.  You probably have a function along the lines of:

```
function main()
    ...
    f(A::Array{Float64}) = # ... some closure
    ...
    f(...)
end
```

But the both ForwardDiff and ReverseDiff require running your program with dual or tracked numbers — which aren't `Float64`.  So you're getting a method error that your closure named `f` doesn't accept arrays of these dual or tracked numbers.

Reduce the specificity of your `f` closure to the widest thing it can support — likely something like `f(A::AbstractArray{<:Number}) = ...`. Note that the two libraries do this slightly differently — ForwardDiff creates an array of Duals whereas ReverseDiff creates a tracked *array* of floating point numbers.  Thus you want both `::AbstractArray` to support more than just `Array`s (you should almost always do this unless you're calling C) and you want to loosen the element type to be any subtype of `Number`. I'd recommend going even further and not care about the element type — you often don't need to care about it.

Answer (score 1):

From the Julia [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.7.0/base/base/#Core.MethodError), the `MethodError: no method matching` is thrown when there is no method with a matching type signature to the one you are calling. Julia has a dynamic type system but allows for type annotations that throw an exception if a value is not of the expected type. Since you are extensively using custom data types, it may be the case that you are passing in a value of custom data type to a method in ForwardDiff/ReverseDiff that expects a different type - hard to confirm without seeing the code but that's where I'd start looking.